# Historically key works on structural reliability theory?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, reference-works, reliability

I want to understand better the structural reliability theory. Is it related to the reliability of structures? Where does it originate and what are the most important work for it?

Answer (score 1):

this reference may be is useful

```
Borgonovo E , Iooss B . Moment-independent and reliability-based importance mea- sures. In: Ghanem R, Higdon D, Owhadi H, editors. Springer handbook on uncer- tainty quantification. Springer; 2017. p. 1265–87 .
```

the book is

```
Handbook of Uncertainty Quantification by 


Roger Ghanem David Higdon Houman Owhadi
```